# Explain this fragment of PHP for me: returning array and immediately reference an index

Tags: php

```
<?php
function ReturnArray() {
    return array('a' => 'f', 'b' => 'g', 'c' => 'h', 'd' => 'i', 'e' => 'j');
}

echo ${!${!1}=ReturnArray()}['a']; // 'f'
?>
```

Please explain what's the logic and step of compute with those ${!1} in the above resolution that works well.

Comment: Winner of the esoteric PHP award goes to ...

Comment: What the answers seem to be missing is that this is a workaround for the fact that `function()[subscript]` is actually (and I wish I were making this up) a *syntax error* in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with some basics. In PHP, something like `hello` will evaluate to the string `"hello"`. To reference a variable, you can use this syntax: `${expr}`. There's also a shorthand for this, `$foo`, which will roughly evaluate to this: `${"foo"}`.

Also, you probably know that you can assign multiple variables at once: `$a=$b=$c='hello';`, for example. This will assign `$a`, `$b`, and `$c` to `'hello'`. This is actually represented as `$a=($b=($c='hello')));`. `$foo=value` is an expression which, after `$foo` is set, will evaluate to `value`.

Your code statement looks like this:

```
echo ${!${!1}=ReturnArray()}['a'];
```

The first thing it does, obviously, is call `ReturnArray`. It then evaluates `!1`, which evaluates to false. The `${!1}` therefore makes a variable with the name `false`, though not a string(?!). After that, it applies a not operation to the array. All non-empty arrays are truthy, so the not operation changes it to `false`. It then uses that `${}` syntax again to retrieve the variable named `false`. It then uses an array access to retrieve the value in the array for key `'a'`.

I hope that made sense.

Comment: My answer is more correct, name of variable is not `false`, but NULL (not as string, as value NULL) :)

Comment: @OZ_: It may be `NULL`, but it can also be referenced by `false`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `!1` = false
2. `${!1}` = NULL
3. `${!1} = ReturnArray()` = array('a' => 'f', 'b' => 'g', 'c' => 'h', 'd' => 'i', 'e' => 'j')
4. so now $NULL contains array
   and again we see construction `${!(condition)` which means $NULL (see first and second points), so we can convert it to:
5. `$NULL['a']` (and $NULL contains array)

You can easily check this:
`print_r(${NULL});` - you'll see array ;)

Answer (score 1):

`${!1}` evaluates to `${false}`
`!${false = ReturnArray()}` evaluates to `$true = array('a' => 'f', /* etc */)`.
`echo $true['a']` produces `'f'` as `'f'` corresponds to index `'a'`

I'm curious now, what is this from?

Comment: we haven't this key in array. And ${0} don't gives to us any identifier.

Comment: Sorry, correct. But `${!1} = 'foo'` followed up with a `print_r(get_defined_vars())` results in `[] => foo` at the bottom of the dump. Er go, it a `false` identifier?

Comment: Always use `var_dump()`; `print_r()` can't even display a boolean properly.

Comment: True that @Alvaro; I typically do.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I've located an answer so I post it here:

```
echo ${!${!1}=ReturnArray()}['a'];

${!${!1}=ReturnArray()}['a']
 !1 resolves to false.

${!${false}=ReturnArray()}['a']
 false resolves to... I don't know. Let's just say false resolves to a variable "a".

${!$a=ReturnArray()}['a']
 $a is now the array. The ! changes the returned array into the boolean false (like: if (!$handle = fopen('x', 'r')) { echo 'connection failed' }.

${false}['a']
 I don't know what false resolves to, but we're using again variable "a".

$a['a'] // this is trivial
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's mostly pure noise. The code assigns an array to a variable and then retrieves key `a`, which is obviously `f`. I just uses booleans to generate the intermediate variable names and let PHP cast them to strings.